# Using query.bindValue() in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I am working on my exam program where we are supposed to make a car dealership database with a gui in QT. Ive come pretty far but i cant for the life of me figure out how to add variables into the query. Ive used sqlite before in c++ where i used the query.bind() function. I could not find that function in QT but i found query.bindValue(), which is supposed to work similary.

This is how i create my car table:

```
void create_table_car()
{
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS car ("
                  "registration_number INTEGER NOT NULL primary key, "
                  "brand VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, "
                  "model VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, "
                  "registration_year INTEGER NOT NULL,"
                  "mileage INTEGER NOT NULL);");
    query.exec();


  if(!query.exec())
  {
      qDebug()<<"Error creating table";
  }
}
```

This is the function where i want the user to be able to add car information to the table:

```
void add_car(int id, QString brand, QString model, int registration_year, int mileage)
{
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare("INSERT INTO car(registration_number, brand, model, registration_year, mileage"
                  "VALUES(:id, ':brand', ':model', :registration_year, :mileage)");
    query.bindValue(":id", id);
    query.bindValue(":brand", brand);
    query.bindValue(":model", model);
    query.bindValue(":registration_year", registration_year);
    query.bindValue(":mileage", mileage);
    query.exec();

    if(!query.exec())
    {
        qDebug()<<"Error adding car";
    }
}
```

I cant seem to figure out how to get bindValue to work, and i keep getting "Error adding car". The connection to the database, and the creation of the table works fine.

This is how i try to test the function:

```
add_car(1, "bmw", "100GT", 2011, 10000);
```

Any help would be greatly appriciated!

Comment: use `qDebug()<<"Error adding car: "<<query.lastError().text()<<query.lastError().nativeErrorCode();` , and tell us which error occured!

Comment: I got this error: Error adding car:  "Parameter count mismatch" "", I dont understand how the parameter amount could be wrong?

Comment: ` query.bindValue(":Model", model); ->     query.bindValue(":model", model);`

Comment: I still get error adding car after fixing the uppercase letter

Comment: I am unsure if :brand and :model needs to be ':brand' and ':model' because they are strings, but ive tried both and i still get error adding car

Comment: Sorry , If Im not suggesting correct way , because I have not the simple project as you have trying, can you just comment out this line: ` query.exec(); `

Comment: And you dont need use ** ' ** for string values .

Comment: Oh you forgot use Braces ")" at the end-> "INSERT INTO car(registration_number, brand, model, registration_year, mileage)"

Comment: After fixing the braces i get this error: Error adding car:  "UNIQUE constraint failed: car.registration_number Unable to fetch row" "1555"

Comment: this is not error on qt usage , it's about sql , I think you added ID that is exist in the table.